# Animation when hovering over a button

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, transition

I am trying to make some animated effect by adding a rectangle that expands over the button when the button (not the rectangle since it's set to `width: 0px;`) is hovered over by the user. Though, I don't really know how to do that, so I'm blocked.

So:

- There's a button.
- There's a rectangle somewhere.
- The rectangle is 0px width.
- I want the **rectangle** to grow from 0 to 200px width when the button is hovered. **NOT** the button.

I accept javascript solutions but only like real basic ones cause I'm a beginner, I won't understand javascript if it's not explained to me.

For the moment, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
   
    <div class="sidebar">

        <button style="margin-top: 100px;" onclick="Accueil()"><div style="z-index: 2;">Accueil</div></button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="acc" style="top: 100px;"></div>

        <button onclick="Thés()"><div style="z-index: 2;">Thés</div></button> 
            <div class="rectangle" name="the" style="top: 100px;"></div>
        
        <button onclick="Tisanes()"><div style="z-index: 2;">Tisanes</div></button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="tis" style="top: 100px;"></div> 

        <button onclick="Théières()"><div style="z-index: 2;">Théières</div></button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="thei" style="top: 100px;"></div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .sidebar > button {
   margin: 20px; /* marge de 30px entre les boutons */
   width: 200px;
   height: 60px;
   max-height: 60px !important;
   max-width: 200px !important; 
   background-color: #F5FAD2;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 24px;
   border-radius: 7%;
   border: none;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #404040;
   position: relative;
   
}

.rectangle {
   width: 0px;
   height: 60px;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.144);
   border-radius: 7%;
   border: none;
   transition: width 1.1s ease 0s;
   transition-timing-function: ease;
   transition-delay: 0s;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}

.rectangle button:hover {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button> Button </button>


button{
  transition:0.2s;
}

button:hover{
  width:200px
}
```

Comment: I don't want the transition on the button, I want the transition on an element named rectangle when the button is hovered over

Answer (score 0):

You can add the transform property in the button CSS class. This will work to increase the size of the rectangle. You can adjust the value inside the scale to get the desired size when hovered. Copy the CSS & HTML codes below to have that working.

CSS:

```
.sidebar>button {
            margin: 20px;
            /* marge de 30px entre les boutons */
            width: 200px;
            height: 60px;
            max-height: 60px !important;
            max-width: 200px !important;
            background-color: #F5FAD2;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            border-radius: 7%;
            border: none;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #404040;
            position: relative;

        }

        .btn:hover {
            width: 300px;
            transform: scale(1.3) perspective(0.4px);
        }

        .rectangle {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.144);
            border-radius: 7%;
            border: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">

        <div class="sidebar">

            <button style="margin-top: 100px;" class="btn">
                <div style="z-index: 2;">Accueil</div>
            </button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="acc" style="top: 100px;"></div>

            <button class="btn">
                <div style="z-index: 2;">Thés</div>
            </button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="the" style="top: 100px;"></div>

            <button class="btn">
                <div style="z-index: 2;">Tisanes</div>
            </button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="tis" style="top: 100px;"></div>
            <button class="btn">
                <div style="z-index: 2;">Théières</div>
            </button>
            <div class="rectangle" name="thei" style="top: 100px;"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this solution helps you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, though after copying this into my code it doesn't do anything. The rectangle is 0px width and I want it to become 200px width when  certain button is hovered, i just don't know what syntax i should use for the css selector to say "when this button is hovered, make that rectangle grow from 0px to 200px width".

Comment: Hi, this should def work. Though I could help you over the chat further if you want! You added the "btn" classes in the button tag too, right?

Comment: I literally copy pasted your code instead of mine. Wanna jump to chat to see the whole thing? That would be really nice (if you want to of course). what your code does is is makes the button larger, but what i want is the button to affect another element

Comment: Hi, sure we could def go over this on chat. What do you mean by the button to affect another element?

Comment: I meant like, it doesn't animate the _button_. It animates **something else** that isn't in the button. For the moment I have a very unprofessional/sloppy alternative! I'll contact you by chat thanks for that by the way.

Comment: oops forgot that I didn't know where is the chat on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to you

```css
.rectangle-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  padding:20px;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
.rectangle-out:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2098D1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.rectangle-out:hover, .rectangle-out:focus, .rectangle-out:active {
  color: white;
}
.rectangle-out:hover:before, .rectangle-out:focus:before, .rectangle-out:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<a class="rectangle-out" href="#">Rectangle Out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have what you are looking for now

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  display: none;
}

.button {
   width: 200px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #F5FAD2;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 24px;
   border-radius: 7%;
   border: none;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #404040;
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

.button:hover + .rectangle {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div style="text-align:center" class="flex-container">
 <div class = "button">Accueil</div>
  <div class="rectangle">test</div>
  <div class = "button">Thés</div>
  <div class="rectangle">test</div>
  <div class = "button">Tisanes</div>
  <div class="rectangle">test</div>
  <div class = "button">Théières</div>
  <div class="rectangle">test</div>
 </div>
```

You can checkout the fiddle I made with this info here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbmarketing4you/j92mgsy6/46/

You have to make the "rectangle" a child of the button in order for the hover effect to work.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. However I don't understand what is this ```.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}
```
and this : .```btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}```

Comment: *Also you said : The transform property needs to be on the button, not on the rectangle.
The thing is I want the rectangle to grow to 200px, not the button

Comment: Why are you wanting the width to grow on the rectangle and not the button? What are you looking to have happen? The code ```.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {   border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */ }``` prevents the button from having double borders on the right side of the button which can actually probably be removed since you have no borders on your buttons.

Comment: Where is the rectangle going to be located? Right now, you have the rectangle located inside the button. Is that where it is going to be?

Comment: @manouna are you wanting something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mbmarketing4you/cm1b6t9L/ I know it doesn't make it wider at the moment, just makes different content show on button click but is that similar to your goal?

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mbmarketing4you/j92mgsy6/

Comment: Updated the code to what I think you are wanting @manouna

Comment: deadline is already beind but that still wasn't it. I guess nobody understood the question lol

Comment: I would say not. You want to try rephrasing or showing me what you are wanting to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful to you.

visit my GitHub page. my website total source code here. many Animation when hovering over a button
here.

https://github.com/jacksonkasi0/mhibuddy

(or) visit my website: https://mahibuddy.me

(or)

HTML:

```
 <div class="lo">
    <ul>
  
  <li>
    <a href="./love/love.html" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    </a> 
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .lo ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}

.lo > ul > li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 15px;}

.lo > ul > li > a {
position: relative; 
display: block;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 63px;
background: #333;
border-radius: 50%;
font-size: 30px;
color: #666;
transition: 0.5s;}

.lo>ul>li>a :hover{
position: relative; 
display: block;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 63px;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 50%;
font-size: 30px;
/* color: #666; */
transition: 0.3s;}

.lo > ul > li > a::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #ff05de;
transition: .5s;
transform: scale(.9);
z-index: -1;}

.lo > ul > li > a:hover::before {
transform: scale(1.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff6e9e;}

.lo > ul > li > a:hover {
color: #ff1058;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff1088;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff1044;}
```